# MongoDB 4.2.5 Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: The server is configured to only allow SSL connections

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodb-.net-driver, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB server from a client application. I have TLS enabled, and I'm using a Self Signed Certificate. The below are the details:

```
OS: Windows Server 2016
MongoDB Version: 4.2.5

mongod.cfg (config file):
net:
   tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateSelector: subject=server1.com
      allowInvalidCertificates: true
      disabledProtocols: none
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: F:\MongoDB\log\mongod.log
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath: F:\MongoDB\data
net:
   bindIp: localhost,server1.com
   port: 27017
```

I have created a RootCA, and created server1.pfx (CN=server1.com). Then exported rootca.cer (with no key) and server1.cer (with no key) and installed them on the server where the client app is running to the Trusted Root Authority (rootca.cer) and Personal (server1.cer).

I'm using the below connection string:

```
mongodb://user:*******************@server1.com:27017/CustomerDB?authSource=CustomerDB&tls=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true
```

Error I get:

```
Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
```

I have added tls=true, and have enabled TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on the server in which the client app is running. I'm able to connect to the MongoDB from a different app, running in a different server with the same connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is not using TLS.

Note that `tls=true` is a relatively recently added option. Be sure you are using a current version of the MongoDB driver.